# javascript: how to access static properties

Tags: javascript, properties, static

I want to access a static property using an instance. Something like this

```
function User(){
    console.log('Constructor: property1=' + this.constructor.property1) ;
}
User.prototype = {
    test: function() {
        console.log('test: property1=' + this.constructor.property1) ;
    }
}    
User.property1 = 10 ;   // STATIC PROPERTY

var inst = new User() ;
inst.test() ;
```

Here is the same code in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FK9VJ/)

In my situation I don't know which class the instance belongs to, so I tried to access the static property using the instance 'constructor' property, without success :(
Is this possible ?

Comment: dont use the word class in javascript

Comment: @Johan: How is that link related to anything here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> so I tried to access the static property using the instance 'constructor' property

That's the problem, your instances don't have a `constructor` property - you've overwritten the whole `.prototype` object and its default properties. Instead, use

```
User.prototype.test = function() {
    console.log('test: property1=' + this.constructor.property1) ;
};
```

And you also might just use `User.property1` instead of the detour via `this.constructor`. Also you can't ensure that all instances on which you might want to call this method will have their `constructor` property pointing to `User` - so better access it directly and explicitly.

Comment: How can I access static property from outside of constructor, or even from static method?

Comment: @AlanKis: Just directly on the constructor, in here for example `User.property1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getObjectClass(obj) {
    if (obj && obj.constructor && obj.constructor.toString) {
        var arr = obj.constructor.toString().match(
            /function\s*(\w+)/);

        if (arr && arr.length == 2) {
            return arr[1];
        }
    }

    return undefined;
}

function User(){
     console.log('Constructor: property1=' + this.constructor.property1) ;
 }

User.property1 = 10 ;

var inst = new User() ;

alert(getObjectClass(inst));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FK9VJ/2/

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you may have a look at: http://jsfiddle.net/etm2d/

```
User.prototype = {
test: function() {
    console.log('test: property1=' + this.constructor.property1) ;
    }
}
```

seems to be problematic, although i haven't yet figured out why.