# Extend class with Plugin Architecture

Tags: typescript

Say I have a class `Test` with a static method `.plugin` which takes a function. That function can run arbitrary code and extend `Test`s API.

```ts
const MyTest = Test.plugin(fooPlugin)
const test = new Test()
const myTest = new MyTest()
test.foo // does not exist
myTest.foo // exists
```

I've made [a TypeScript Playground that I hope is close to working](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?target=5#code/C4TwDgpgBAgmCWBRAHsCA7AzvA9uqAvFAN5QDaA1hCAFxSbABO86A5gLp0CG6IUAvgCgIyMDkbAooSFAAKAGwCurFoSgAKFgx4BjCHQAqEBgEpCAPlgIUaLLnQBuQdOgBhPA0aKdwcQB4DSyJ0CAB3DQA6KK5GVkxuXjJ2MwJLAydBHXkuTEwoIwYSQSh6YC5geB0oMCUVLDoFZRYktSSnEu0Kqpqm9HUeuobaljNiYpKoHQ9JHUVGRgxgRrq8omAAC3hMCIGtDInJ7NyoADkwgskRWwATPI2tooOOsq7q4aw1WfnF5a0IqfQOnK-XeJnaEyE4xKLigNgw2DwagAShBgHN0AZwBA-C4cAAzN69cxQqALNGMfBnUIXKA5KRY-Gnc7GSQAMig7iwTG8vkYfjhdjw5nBkJKAM8PPE6lGJIA9LLaWAanxdlg5Qr1sBgGB4vLtDoKDgAG4QRh4+Q4UL-HAAW1lXFlAEYAGwAZgALABWR0AdgATCTxTMjphORKfOI1PdtkGvBHGLS7gyCRdwWKQ2HufGdu9tnjxIguDp1iDehZHk8APIAIwAVhAfBEcthWH1owAaQl1dTRkwmEn8MHjUXkKi0UrMNicWm8QSQ+VQACKihZ9jo60tUhwUBtXCo+SxmB0zDAkkU6Gupu0F6k63KUAAsiAaVoyoDjFA7ybaVAIvmcNKO6ohu1xQOgloAPzOFi+Qsr86ACgi+BEGMJT-tKdAAOTVjEmFzoImTTLBDDwWoPYsoYLImJRJHvIh9jlqhkweDg8gQBEFqsOomGqlAEBGlwShoJgmH9uMZLohWaE4DgdCAakUDYbhw74UGj7PiyagXDmvTqBc8H9mpNoaYUwRhOpFzSkAA)

When I add `myTest.foo` to the end of the example, `.foo` is typed as `any`. I would expect that the `<typeof plugin>` would return the type of the `plugin` function that I pass, not the generic specification?

If I replace `<typeof plugin>` with `<typeof TestPlugin>` then it works as expected.

Is there anything I can do to make this work, without changing the way the Plugin Architecture currently works?

If I slightly change the code ([Playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-iQqYi8hUWilZhsThU3iCGFyqAARUUzPsdE2FqkOCg1q4VHyuMwOmYYEkinQtxN2kvUk25SgAFkQJStGVgcYoPfjVSoBE8zgUq7him63FA6AWgA-M4uL5My-z8si+BEJMJQAVKdAAORVjEmHzoImRzHBDD-GobbMoYzImJRJHgoh9hlqhMweDg8gQBE5qsOomEqlAECGlwShoJgmEDlMxJYuWaE4DgdBAakUDYbhI74YGT4vsyahXNmPZXP8A5qdaGmFMEYTqVcUqCEZ2kAUAA)), `myTest.foo` gets typed correctly, but there are two TypeScript errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your modified approach is almost correct, just that `T = Plugin` is a default value of `Plugin` for the type parameter `T`, but `T` can be any other type not necessarily a subtype of `Plugin`. You want to say `T extends Plugin` which means `T` must be a subtype of `Plugin`.

Also you don't need the index signature in `Test` (at least not as far as the plugin architecture is concerned). This will make missing members an error as well (the index signature would hide those):

```
type ApiExtension = { [key: string]: any }
export type Plugin = (instance: Test) => ApiExtension;
type Constructor<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

class Test {
  static plugins: Plugin[] = [];
  static plugin<T extends Plugin>(plugin: T) {
    const currentPlugins = this.plugins;

    class NewTest extends this {
      static plugins = currentPlugins.concat(plugin);
    }

    type Extension = ReturnType<T>
    return NewTest as typeof NewTest & Constructor<Extension>;
  }

  constructor() {
    // apply plugins
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/16345172
    const classConstructor = this.constructor as typeof Test;
    classConstructor.plugins.forEach(plugin => {
      Object.assign(this, plugin(this))
    });
  }
}

// Question: how to make Typescript understand that MyTest instances have a .foo() method now?
type TestPluginExtension = {
  foo(): 'bar'
}

const TestPlugin = (test: Test): TestPluginExtension => {
  console.log('plugin evalutes')

  return {
    foo: () => 'bar'
  }
}
const MyTest = Test.plugin(TestPlugin)
const myTest = new MyTest()
myTest.foo()
myTest.fooo() //err
```

[Play](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=43&pc=20#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-Xo914mEyk-iw+ZCBFKqAARUU7PsdD2NqkOCg9q4VHyhMwOmYYEkinQQwt2lPL3KUAAsiBaVoyuDjFA9lxzXSoBFizg5ZucauQxQOgNoAPzOISGYMMCwrovgRDvFAP5ynQADkDYxKhggIqGUFbNCag9uyhjsiYJHQdCsH2NWiFSjg8gQBE1qsOoqEagMppcEoaCYKhY7zOSeI1gsP50H+qRQOhmFTthmTLLe97smo9wFkO9zAmOuH2ophTBGECn3HKgjaSpyFjiZ7Lfjg1l-kqFqMEAA)

Comment: That all makes sense. Thanks so much Titian!

Comment: I've created a follow up question to allow the static `.plugin()` method to also accept an array of plugins: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58612535/intersection-types-from-variable-array-of-types I tried to figure out if what I want to do is possible to type at all ... but no luck. Got any idea?