# Intersection Types from variable array of types

Tags: typescript

This is a follow up question to [Extend class with Plugin Architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58600812/206879)

I have a class `Test` with a static method `.plugin` which takes a function. That function can run arbitrary code and extend `Test`s API.

```js
const FooTest = Test.plugin(FooPlugin)
const fooTest = new FooTest()
fooTest.foo()
```

`FooPlugin` returns an object { foo(): 'foo' } which is combined with the prototype of `Test` when cretaing `FooTest`. That part is working.

Now I would like the static `.plugin()` method to also accept an array of Plugins, so I don't need to create a new Class each time I call the `.plugin()` method, but only once. The returned class should reduce the array of return types into a single object and merge that with `Test`s prototype.

Here is the resulting Code I'd like to make possible

```js
const FooBarTest = Test.plugin([FooPlugin, BarPlugin])
const fooBarTest = new FooBarTest()
fooBarTest.foo()
fooBarTest.bar()
```

Is that possible at all? I've created a [TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=15&ssc=1&pln=17&pc=1#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-BWOgVF9MAAaQFdZ-jslaxF+wQopOUAAGI4DgEKGqoaAMDUBh0KQ244KGdAAOSIShAjHssS7ODgMgQCExasCoKHxr0uZcPI0EofoggrJa-IngUiF0KGx5oWBKH-kIQEAEIRBByjPjksHAPo8FQOeETIVAKFSYwGH8FhKy9nhBFESRZEQBRVGSDRdE8syVrYas8msQkJhyREXEFEIgEbCBYEvEQIwbp+oHgQiqQOYhzlQAEwQeSMoaCL5OQhIhIXefKjk4PxjB+a58YqGQHkQe+8UQfE0V9oh8V+QFsX5TkIV5RErmRbRZUJeF8mhkAA), lines 15-16 require changes to make it all possible. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case anyone is interested, here's how I arrived at the solution.

**Switching the type parameters**

The challenge of this task was to extract the return type not only from a single function but from an array of functions as well. I needed a conditional type that would accept either a single `TestPlugin` or an array of those, and produce two different results depending on what was provided:

- If a single `TestPlugin` was provided, extract its return type.
- If `TestPlugin[]` was provided, create an intersection of all return types.

Since the conditional type I had in mind would accept a union of `TestPlugin | TestPlugin[]`, I had to declare one in the scope of the `plugin` method. Let's switch the definition from this:

```
static plugin<T extends TestPlugin>(plugin: T | T[])
```

to this:

```
static plugin<T extends (TestPlugin | TestPlugin[])>(plugin: T)
```

Now we have a `T` we can work with.

**Building the conditional type**

The final version of the conditional type looks like this:

```
type ReturnTypeOf<T extends AnyFunction | AnyFunction[]> =
  T extends AnyFunction
    ? ReturnType<T>
      : T extends AnyFunction[]
        ? UnionToIntersection<ReturnType<T[number]>>
        : never
```

To pull it off, I need two helper types. The first is `AnyFunction`. This makes `ReturnTypeOf` work with any functions, not just `TestPlugin`, but we could have used `TestPlugin` just as well if we don't plan on reusing `ReturnTypeOf` in other places.

```
type AnyFunction = (...args: any) => any;
```

Another type is the famous transformation by the great [@jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz). If `T` is an array of functions, and arrays are indexed by numbers, then `T[number]` is a union of all members of that array. It's called a *lookup type*.

We could call `ReturnType` on an array of functions (and get a union of their return types back), but that's not what we want. We want their *intersection*, not their union. `UnionToIntersection` will do that for us.

```
/**
 * @author https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286/10325032
 */
type UnionToIntersection<Union> =
  (Union extends Unrestricted
    ? (argument: Union) => void
    : never
  ) extends (argument: infer Intersection) => void // tslint:disable-line: no-unused
      ? Intersection
      : never;
```

**Replacing `ReturnType` with our custom `ReturnTypeOf`**

When we inspect the type of `T` in the scope of `Test.plugin`, we notice it's always either a plugin or an array of plugins. Even the type guard (`Array.isArray(plugin)`) didn't help TypeScript discriminate that union. And since the built-in `ReturnType` cannot accept arrays, we need to replace both instances of `ReturnType` with our custom `ReturnTypeOf`.

**Final solution**

```
type ApiExtension = { [key: string]: any }
type TestPlugin = (instance: Test) => ApiExtension;
type Constructor<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

/**
 * @author https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286/10325032
 */
type UnionToIntersection<Union> =
  (Union extends any
    ? (argument: Union) => void
    : never
  ) extends (argument: infer Intersection) => void // tslint:disable-line: no-unused
      ? Intersection
      : never;

type AnyFunction = (...args: any) => any;

type ReturnTypeOf<T extends AnyFunction | AnyFunction[]> =
  T extends AnyFunction
    ? ReturnType<T>
      : T extends AnyFunction[]
        ? UnionToIntersection<ReturnType<T[number]>>
        : never

class Test {
  static plugins: TestPlugin[] = [];
  static plugin<T extends TestPlugin | TestPlugin[]>(plugin: T) {
    const currentPlugins = this.plugins;

    class NewTest extends this {
      static plugins = currentPlugins.concat(plugin);
    }

    if (Array.isArray(plugin)) {
      type Extension = ReturnTypeOf<T>
      return NewTest as typeof NewTest & Constructor<Extension>;  
    }

    type Extension = ReturnTypeOf<T>
    return NewTest as typeof NewTest & Constructor<Extension>;
  }

  constructor() {
    // apply plugins
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/16345172
    const classConstructor = this.constructor as typeof Test;
    classConstructor.plugins.forEach(plugin => {
      Object.assign(this, plugin(this))
    });
  }
}

const FooPlugin = (test: Test): { foo(): 'foo' } => {
  console.log('plugin evalutes')

  return {
    foo: () => 'foo'
  }
}
const BarPlugin = (test: Test): { bar(): 'bar' } => {
  console.log('plugin evalutes')

  return {
    bar: () => 'bar'
  }
}

const FooTest = Test.plugin(FooPlugin)
const fooTest = new FooTest()
fooTest.foo()

const FooBarTest = Test.plugin([FooPlugin, BarPlugin])
const fooBarTest = new FooBarTest()
fooBarTest.foo()
fooBarTest.bar()
```

[TypeScript Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=28&ssc=28&pln=28&pc=53#code/C4TwDgpgBAgmCWBRAHsCA7AzvA9uqAvFAN5QDaA1hCAFxSbABO86A5gLp0CG6IUAvgChQkKABUIDAAoAbAK6sWhKAAoWDHgGMIdCQwCUhAHywEKNFlzoA3MPDQAwngaM5m4DkYAeMSaLoIAHdVADowrkZWTG5eMnZDAhMxW0EAegAqdMEodKgAAS45YAALTyhi4GAwaNTUjU0KHAA3CEYAMxkcQJDNHABbVLlMVsxUgCYADgmAdjGARgnUgCtNLhkAL2zcvOHoCqqauuAuBubWjq6e-tSuVIBWAAYAZmm7yYA2VLnnscensa2qTsogAqugrGIcABJdBoRjDdxWLxgqx+bKqFF4KAQVAYAAmmCgPBA6KgUAA-KoIqw5H0MMA6Jj0AkTE0cPA8aSoHQAi1GOjDDiLASqZFafS6Cw2q0oDC4QjgFYWVA2RyoLUoMBMDIWAy8fBMFwAEYyCAAWh1AR5ODNcnQQwgnLJzopsthIwgiLwXLJPIgfJSImgMF4ADE7V78EQVGEQtTokTeMriYH7FAAEoQYByRjoMT2ADybR82Nx6BFIZA4fQkagAB9YGGI4q8HE0WSxKXhYTK9XI1zKZns7n85AfEYfdzxF38T2mzWW+g4pOyZSmZC5R7I14hzm8-YfGR7X0ja12EYJy6XX6+YJBJoZFxMIS9MASOiNIrNFAwPJFFhdEkYBZAUFg4mUOJbDJT94G-X9QPQEshVnVRXxA-963EID0LA+IjBUeD-10QxiC5XosDfTQc0YekcKwZQSgNEJCPUFIXQfJ9CQAOSCV8Z3LQlGMJUir3oY4vx-P91GUKjGBo2E6MwK4ay4YACKk5koOdIQuXgNpVBgOSuBAEIDUMxhjPUhD9BIycgygcwMGwLEiF3EdC2LXxJxo4d8B4wI+KfTV7BwfT-L4gAyKAnAo1x3E8LxHMsPAjGsMkuR0l17KS5yowzLM91HCAi3HLkfL3KBwqAolBJCsLeOqqKYpcNwPG8HLUS0zKoHIlr4sYFRbJdDUuDAX8+BYrAuQ1fZqhoWp6kaPkLm6XoBluOZ3ieAAWO45lmMjnEox9n2aphWrKIghOUvq2pq4LIFCrCGC0skONOo64ra5iNKUtpPEQE5iisjDEnfUSCyNJZPWAONn3gVh0BUISABpJIQ5HigNGyMv0LrBB03q31DHAcDo5RkaAwCDDoUh-pwQa6AAcnppmBGMcGeucHBTRCTpWBUJnJuxJo1iKSQmf0O8yXK3NObJem6EGjmWdJpn0SEIQiagAAhCJyejNAGGp4B9FpqAjQiRmoCZy3GDZ-gOZErmsB5iA+ZwAWhY0kWxaNyXpagWX8Gdsk7aV5VbYidWyU1u9tZJnA+KIV8foxxO6Kl7X6eTqAAmCRPX0GwQc6AkJ6eL+8jqgRO9cYXPU8mlQyAzjS0bruj4iriioHpuvc-zmvSf7oDi77iJU4rqXx-rsu7cGoA)

Comment: Good job! If the `plugin` function definition has to remain the same like in above question, you could even use the default `ReturnType` directly together with `UnionToIntersection`. [sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-knarwj) (playground URL didn't fit here)

Comment: Correct! For TypeScript, both cases are the same so there is no need to create two branches. Good catch.

Answer (score 0):

Karol from WrocTypeScript figured it out: [Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=72&pc=17#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-Hq5tQdMM-BV0I1xYLFw4Oev98AMigdwsCYbxfEYPwDzsPBzAccYNWnCF939I98CIG9fXvFYnylKBf2MSQDSkLJv1w6t8KgACgM8UD-EglCYOWBCoGHaifHEdQdwhAB6LjFjAa0+CLLANR4qAc2AYAwHiHjtB0CgcGRL55BwUIhxwLYuK4LiAEYADYAGYABYAFZtIAdgAJkTZNmP1Q0qJAtjGGzPMCxYxywI-IjIBImtJ3GMt7OTLwnMLTsCy+cREC4HQc03YNUibZsAHlFQAKzFcpDXgVh0HUBtMAAGg7H18tc7d4InRjBGndyoFyHAcAHEo0AYQx8JMOhSEinAOLoAByHr+oEEEEwCjwcHkCAImU1h1H6oTpmOLglFa-qTB1cZsNxJLxh6ugOJBQbGv66qhDqgAhGJmqIfL8Pa0wuqgRUYj6qB+pexhhv4UblhYybptm+bFqRFbFDWjblm2-AxpWT6DqOD6YlO8YhFqmyGpwd8iBrMLSsxgcNrqnrsagEJwkxmsOMEEn8IiHrqd1DHGquxhSdxoT1DIAnO2K1mB2SJngKgHrWdJ8n6pZmIqY20XpbphnZaltm6c+jigA)